# error en dimensionamiento para sinusoidal positional embedding

Tags: nlp

Intentando crear una clase para sinusoidal positional embedding y parece que estoy obteniendo un error en las dimensiones del tensor **positional_embeddings**.Parece que se debe al reshape que se hace al positional_embeddings; no soy experto en tensorflow y no entiendo a que se debe. Alguien sabe el motivo? De antemano gracias por su ayuda!

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers
def TokenAndPositionEmbedding(maxlen, vocab_size, embed_dim):
    class _TokenAndPositionEmbedding(layers.Layer):
        def __init__(self, maxlen, vocab_size, embed_dim):
            super(_TokenAndPositionEmbedding, self).__init__()
            self.token_emb = layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=embed_dim)
            self.pos_emb = layers.Embedding(input_dim=maxlen, output_dim=embed_dim)
            self.vocab_size= vocab_size
            self.embed_dim= embed_dim
            #self.maxlen= maxlen

        def call(self, x):
            maxlen = tf.shape(x)[-1]

            # Create word embeddings
            position = tf.range(1, maxlen+1, dtype=tf.float32)[:, tf.newaxis]
            div_term = tf.exp(tf.range(0, self.embed_dim, 2, dtype=tf.float32) * -(tf.math.log(10000.0) / self.embed_dim))
            sin_terms = tf.math.sin(position * div_term)
            cos_terms = tf.math.cos(position * div_term)
            # Interleave the sin and cos terms
            positional_embeddings = tf.reshape(tf.stack([sin_terms, cos_terms], axis=2), shape=(maxlen, self.embed_dim))
            x = self.token_emb(x)
            positional_embeddings= self.pos_emb(positional_embeddings)

            return x + positional_embeddings
    return _TokenAndPositionEmbedding(maxlen, vocab_size, embed_dim)

Dimensions must be equal, but are 30 and 64 for
```